# Are transpilers still needed for ecma6 and react?

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, syntax, ecmascript-6, transpiler

I am using a babel transpiler for react ecma6 projects ,but It seems that chrome already supports ecma6 functions, methods and syntax. Is the transpiler really needed. syntax wize, what is the traspiler part in the workflow? Which functions or methods arent supported in chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mario about http://caniuse.com/, and you can get more detail on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript for each browser feature you may need.

Always consider your lowest common demoninator. Usually IE, but sometimes that depends these days with FF, Safari mobile, etcetera. If your lowest required browser/platform does not support the feature, you can use something like a [Babble module](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) to transpile on-the-fly, or just grab the polyfills from MDN which usually has well written and maintained code.

About polyfills - in case you venture to write your own:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/369858/Writing-polyfills-in-Javascript
- http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/06/writing-javascript-polyfill/

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://caniuse.com/, a site to check compatibility/implementation status.

Personally, I would still transpile at this time as not everyone uses Chrome as their browser. If you know you only have Chrome clients (intranet for example), you can use most ES6 features.

A huge feature for me are `imports` and `exports` which are not part of most browsers at this time, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thnx, import and export are great features for development stages. But at the end I Need to bundle up all the code into one file, which makes them irrelevant. Could there be issues with react jsx, without the transpiler?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Yes there could be issues. Since you are bundling, you might as well go the webpack/browserify route and transpile your code in the process. While you are doing it, you might also want to minify/uglify your code for performance. :)

Comment: @ShaiKimchi JSX won't work without transpilation since it's not, and will probably never become, part of ES/JS.